# How to transfer data between fragment and non parent activity?

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am very struggling to solve this problem

[image]

I am listening data from conversation list fragment

Now how to send received data in chatting activity when chatting is going on? Please help.

Comment: Can you show how you make the start/call for the Chatting activity?

Comment: Intent chattingIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), 
                    ChattingActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putParcelable("User",conversation.getUser());
                    chattingIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(chattingIntent);

Comment: @Shahzeb please can you put the code in the question? just need to edit. And don't need to comment like "Can Anyone help?" you are already asking your question, if people can they will help ˆˆ

Comment: @Shahzeb you can pass the data using the bundle, like you passed the user.

Comment: @Canato I want live data transmission
means conversationslist fragment listens incoming messages data from server.for example I am chatting with you and conversationlist fragment is listening incoming messages when  it receives message from your side it send message object to chatting activity in which I am chatting with you

Comment: @Shahzeb maybe you are looking this with the wrong perspective, but why should the fragment listening the conversation while the fragment is OnStop and the user are in the Activity Screen? Will not be better solution, easy and good coded/split if the action that you need in the fragment happen in the fragment?

Comment: So should I use chatting fragment instead of chatting activity?
and which is the good place to listen incoming messages?

Comment: Did you consider `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: About fragment and activity is another question. But on conversation list maybe you just need the last message or only the contact. And inside the real chat screen you listen the whole chat

Comment: yes but conversation's unread counts?
and how to deal with incoming conversation which are not still in conversation list?

Comment: have you read [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) and [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) stuff? and [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) in general?

Comment: reading but some suggested about Eventbus

Comment: what is the problem with LocalBroadcast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undestood the problem correctly, this seems like a job for an EventBus. Have a look on how to implement it here : http://square.github.io/otto/

First of all you need to define a event

```
public class ChatMessage{
   private String status,message,sender;
   //with constructors and toString
}
```

In your Chatting activity you post the event on the event bus, something like this

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new ChatMessage(status,message,sender)
```

In your Conversation list (assuming you're displaying with a List or Recyclerview managed by an adapter) , make the adapter aware of your event bus

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void updateAdapter(ChatMessage message) {
    //here you should get the chat item and update it
    //do not forget to call notifyDatasetChanged() at the end to update your adapter
}
```

Post a message to the EventBus at anytime you want the Conversation list fragment to be updated(eg. when a message is incoming , when you are sending a message to a contact)

If you can provide additional code form your fragments/activities and form the adapter I'll update my answer.

Comment: As I understood,It with get data from chatting activity and send it to conversationlist fragment.
but I want reverse of it means conversationlist fragment is listening incoming messages from server and saving these data to sqlite too,
assume that I am chatting with you and conversationlist fragment is listening incoming messages when it receives message from your side it send message object to chatting activity in which I am chatting with you

Comment: In that case you would need 2 types of messages , and post them on the event bus . In the conversation list you will handle one type and in the chatting activity the other one . In the conversation list , if you need to update from the server I would recommend using Retrofit and RxJava.

Comment: I am using Firebase.
and from chatting activity i am sending message object with LocalBroadcast

Answer (score 2):

The `ChattingActivity` is a separate `Activity` which requires to have a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen to the new chat messages received in `ConversationListFragment`.

The implementation of setting up a `BroadcastReceiver` is fairly simple. Take this as an example. The `ChattingActivity` will have these things in it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Other code ...

  // Register to receive messages.
  // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
  // with actions named "new-chat-message".
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("new-chat-message"));
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "new-chat-message" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("receiver", "New chat message received: " + message);
  }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Now the `ConversationListFragment` should send the broadcast accordingly when a new chat message is received using the same topic name. Let us assume there's a function in `ConversationListFragment` which is `onNewMessageReceived`. The parameter of the function which is `newMsg` which is the message received by the application in `ConversationListFragment`.

```
// Send an Intent with an action named "new-chat-message". The Intent sent should 
// be received by the ChattingActivity.
private void onNewMessageReceived(String newMsg) {
  Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting new chat message");
  Intent intent = new Intent("new-chat-message");
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", newMsg);
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

You might consider passing additional parameters as well. For example, the new message is received for other conversation, which is not opened right now in `ChattingActivity`. So the `ChattingActivity` should not be updated in that case. So we should send a flag, like `otherPartyAccountId` indicating which person I am chatting with. So if the `ChattingActivity` is opened with a person, but the message is received for another person, the current `ChattingActivity` should not be updated.

I would suggest to open the `ChattingActivity` as another `Fragment` under the `HostingActivity`. Which will make the whole process flow a lot simplified.

Comment: let me apply it

Comment: Thank u @Raez it is solved..work like a charm

Comment: Great to know that! Glad that helped.