# Fragment loses focus in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am working on a music player. There are two activities. The first activity is a `ViewPager` which contains four fragments (All songs, Playlist, Albums and Artist). The other `Activity` is used to list the songs of a particular playlist. Everything works fine when playing music from the first fragment (i.e. all songs) in the `ViewPager`. Now when I open a playlist from the second fragment it opens up the new `Activity` listing the songs in that playlist. When I click to play, it plays fine. However, when I go back to the previous activity (i.e. `ViewPager`) and I try to play a song in the 1st fragment (i.e. all songs), it plays the song from the predecessor playlist which is from the previous `Activity`. It seems like the `Fragment` loses its focus despite it been visible and its `RecyclerView` click doesn't work. It works for the previous, maybe because it uses the same adapter class for their `RecyclerView`. I don't know what am I doing wrong here. Please help.

**This is my ViewPager code.**

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        Intent service = new Intent(this, MyMusicPlayerService.class);
        bindService(service, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new MyMusic();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new PlayList();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new Albums();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new Artist();
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.title1);
                case 1:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.title2);
                case 2:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.title3);
                case 3:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.title4);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**The All Songs Fragment:** I am writing the `onCreateView()` method first fragment of the `ViewPager`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_music, container, false);
    storage = new Storage(getActivity());
    rvAdapter = new RVAdapter(musics, getActivity(), "all");
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    rvAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RVAdapter.OnRvItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRvItemClickListener(ArrayList<String> data, int position) {
            storage.storeSongs(musics); //stores all musics of the current list in an Array, in case of next and prev
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(position);
        }
    });

    rvAdapter.setOnOptionClickListener(new RVAdapter.OnOptionClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOptionClick(String mode, ArrayList<String> data) {
            processOption(mode, data);
        }
    });

    populate(); // function to populate recyclerview
    recycler.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

**Second Activity:** This is the `onCreate()` method for the second activity that lists the song of a particular playlist opened from the 2nd tab(Playlist) in the first activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_song);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(updateReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_INFO));

    storage = new Storage(this);
    playinfo = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.playinfo);
    prev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prev);
    playpause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playpause);
    fwd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fwd);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    artist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist);

    playinfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    prev.setOnClickListener(this);
    playpause.setOnClickListener(this);
    fwd.setOnClickListener(this);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    empty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);

    rvAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RVAdapter.OnRvItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRvItemClickListener(ArrayList<String> data, int position) {
            storage.storeSongs(musics); //stores all musics of the current list in an Array, in case of next and prev
            Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_INFO);
            intent.putExtra("title", data.get(0));
            intent.putExtra("artist", data.get(1));
            intent.putExtra("playStatus", "play");
          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
            storage.storeAudioIndex(position);
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyMusicPlayerService.class);
            intent2.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
            startService(intent2);//play music

            updateBottom();
        }
    });

    rvAdapter.setOnOptionClickListener(new RVAdapter.OnOptionClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOptionClick(String mode, ArrayList<String> data) {
            processOption(mode, data);
        }
    });

    recycler.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too board to answer. However, I thought I could give you an insight of the solution to your problem and hence I am writing an answer.

From my understanding the `Home` activity hosts the four `Fragment` in a `ViewPager`. All of these four fragments contain `RecyclerView` to list different things. But hence clicking on any item in the `RecyclerView` in any of these four `Fragment` brings up the `SecondActivity` which contains a list of songs. So as far as I have understood, you can play songs from two different places. One is the first `Fragment` in the `ViewPager` which is labeled as All Songs and the another one is from the list that you have inside `SecondActivity` for all other three `Fragment` in the `ViewPager`.

Now, I would like to suggest a design flow which will help you to have control over the song that you are playing.

You need to host two `Fragment` in your `Home` activity. A `Fragment` will be `ViewPagerContainerFragment` and the other will be the `SecondFragment`. Convert your `SecondActivity` as the `SecondFragment` here and move the `ViewPager` related code from your `Home` activity to `ViewPagerContainerFragment`. By default, set the `ViewPagerContainerFragment` in the fragment container of the `Home` activity.

Let us have a public function in the `Home` activity that hosts these two `Fragment`. I am just giving you a sample, please modify the function parameter as per your requirement.

```
public void playSong (List<Music> musics, int position, ArrayList<String> data) {
    storage.storeSongs(musics); //stores all musics of the current list in an Array, in case of next and prev
    Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_INFO);
    intent.putExtra("title", data.get(0));
    intent.putExtra("artist", data.get(1));
    intent.putExtra("playStatus", "play");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    storage.storeAudioIndex(position);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyMusicPlayerService.class);
    intent2.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
    startService(intent2); //play music

    updateBottom();
}
```

I do not know what you are exactly doing with `storage` and the `data`, but the idea is to pass necessary parameters to the `playSong` function to play the specific song and handle the next and previous song properly from the specific list. It would be great if you could just pass the name of the list and the index of the song from that list in the `playSong` function. So that we could play the song from a single place.

Now, as you have wrote the function `playSong` perfectly in the `Home` activity which handles playing a song and maintains the previous and next song along with the specific list from where the song is playing, our problem is nearly solved. Try to keep a static variable of your `Service` intent, so that each time you do not re-initialize the `MyMusicPlayerService` class.

The next step will be removing the code for playing a song from everywhere other than the `playSong` function that we have now in the `Home` activity.

From the `AllSongsFragment` modify the click action on `RecyclerView` like this.

```
rvAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RVAdapter.OnRvItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRvItemClickListener(ArrayList<String> data, int position) {
        ((Home) getActivity()).playSong(...); // Call the public function that you have declared in Home activity. 
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(position);
    }
});
```

And from the `SecondFragment` call the `playSong()` function in the same manner which will play the song for you.

**Another approach**

I can think of another approach without changing the `SecondActivity` to `Fragment` and keeping the current structure. This might be solved using a `LocalBroadcastReceiver`. You might consider having a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Host` activity and on receiving the broadcast send from the `SecondActivity` and `AllSongsFragment` it will play the song accordingly from a single place. If you want to have a basic idea on how `BroadcastReceiver` works, you may look into [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48720226/3145960) for better understanding. The idea is to play and track the song from a single static place.

Comment: However, i noticed that when i go back to the previous `activity`(Home) using `intent` (by overriding the `onBackPressed()`), the error doesn't come up. The fragments are recreated and everything seems to work normal

Comment: What are the tasks you are going through while overriding the `onBackPressed` method? And yes, when you go back using the back navigation button in the action bar, the problem persists? You may consider overriding the action of back button in the navigation bar as well in the `onOptionsItemSelected` function.

Comment: yes i did that, the task is just to switch to the previous activity, 'Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class) startActivity(intent)` . it works now, but this approach doesnt seem efficient and not a good practise i think. onBackPressed should just take its course, rather than specifying an activity

Comment: Oh, you are creating another instance of the `Home` activity. Right. Yes, there are better approaches that I have suggested already. You might consider trying one of those.